# Spring MVC get value from ajax and Mapping with add to <form:select>

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Is it possible to add Select option by Mapping with Model without response to ajax? 
Now, I add options to select by response to ajax and using for loop 
My View

```
function addfunction(){
    var valuess = $("#test01").val();
    var base_url = window.location.origin;
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",  
        url: base_url+"/testCalling",
        data: "values="+values,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("ok");
        }
    });
}

<form:label path="test01">Test01</form:label>
<form:input path="test01"/>
<form:select path="result01" items="${result01}" />
<button type="button" onclick="addfunction()">Add</button>
```

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testCalling", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView details(@RequestBody GroupRuleModel groupRuleModel, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        //SQL get values and add to Select option without response to ajax
    }
```

My Model

```
private String test01;
private String result01;

public String getResult01() {
    return result01;
}
public void setResult01(String result01) {
    this.result01 = result01;
}
public String getTest01() {
    return test01;
}
public void setTest01(String test01) {
    this.test01 = test01;
}
```

Comment: 1. Set another Map variable to your model with getter/setter.
2. Set the variable value from your controller.
3. Get the value and use it to add options from your view.

Comment: @Jejun Can you show example?